# glm rotate and translation

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I have a `mat4` called `model`. I want my cube to orbit around a position. I am able to call the `glm::rotate(mat4, angle, vec3)` just fine and have it rotate at its origin.

```
void Object::Update(unsigned int dt)
{
  angle += dt * M_PI/1000;
  model = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), (angle), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
  model = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f));
}
```

Unfortunately my cube is frozen in place when I add the `glm::translate` call after the rotation. Is there something basic I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass it the result of the rotation as the initial matrix: `model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f));`. Otherwise you are resetting and translating the Identity matrix, which will completely overwrite your rotation.